# Trouble with getting data into JSON dict from html file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to scrape a website and so far my code has gotten me the copied html code below. However, I want to access the variable tablelist, specifically the 'defjson:' part and parse the data in there.
It looks like the .split('\n') is not working, but splitting on spaces does not work because the data in defjson has some random spaces. Is there any other way to access defjson?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function _doZoom(t){
        setCookie(fontCookieName,h,9999);
        var a=document.getElementsByTagName("dl");
        var k=[],c=[],g=[];
        var b=a.length;
        for(var f=0;f<b;f++){
            if(a[f].getElementsByTagName("span").length>0){
                g.push(a[f]);k.push(a[f].getElementsByTagName("span")[0]);
                c.push(a[f].getElementsByTagName("span")[1])
            }
        }
        b=g.length;
        var e=document.getElementById("combinationsContainer");
        switch(parseInt(h)){
            case 0:e.style.fontSize="14px";
                for(var d=0;d<b;d++){
                    k[d].className="at";c[d].className=""
                }break;
            case 1:e.style.fontSize="12px";
                for(var d=0;d<b;d++){k[d].className="";c[d].className="at"
                }break
        }
    } 
    var tablelist = new LoadTable({
        id: "dt_1",
        sort: { id: "12", desc: true },
        cells: [{ "n": "股票<font class=\"ssp\" style=\"text-decoration:           underline;\">代码</font>", "s": "5" }, { "n": "股票<font class=\"ssp2\">简称</font>", "w": "58" }, { "n": "相关资料", "w": "120" }, { "n": "申购<br />代码", "w": "44" }, { "n": "发行<br />总数<br />(万股)", "s": "7" }, { "n": "网上<br />发行<br />(万股)", "s": "8" }, { "n": "顶格申购<br />需配市值<br />(万元)<i title=\"黑色斜体部分为预估值，顶格申购需配市值的预估不涉及公司基本面分析，请谨慎参考。\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>" }, 
        dataurl: "http://datainterface.eastmoney.com/EM_DataCenter/JS.aspx?type=NS&sty=NSST&st={sortType}&sr={sortRule}&p={page}&ps={pageSize}&js=var {jsname}={pages:(pc),data:[(x)]}{param}", ...
        defjson:{pages:18,data:[",23772,80199130,万里石,002785,002785,50000000.00,20000000.00,,,,2015-07-08,2015-07-13,,,,,,,zxb,500.00,,,,,,http://topic.eastmoney.com/XMWLSIPO/,中高端石材综合服务商&sbquo;一直专注于建筑装饰石材及景观石材的研发设计、生产和销售。,2.29,2.00,4.59,,0,,2.29,2,4.58,20.00,待上市,,,,,AN201506250010008785,22.9,41.15"
```

```
def scrape():
    htmltext = open('test.html','r').read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    scripts = bs.find_all('script')[-3]
    print scripts
```

so far my code gets the above part of the html file
I tried adding in:

```
 for line in scripts.split('\n'):

     if (line.startswith('defjson: ')):

         jsonStr=line.replace('defjson: ','')

         dataDict = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

but it gives me a Nonetype error
Is there a better way to access the defjson: part and load it into a dictionary?

Comment: a) the line starts with ``defjson:``, no space there. b) the line misses some closing brackets and braces. Does that already help?

Comment: Thank you, that helped. The code now shows me local variable 'dataDict' referenced before assignment when I try to print it.

Comment: I think the problem is also that the .split('\n') is not working correctly and isn't giving me separate lines

Comment: Try defining it before you do the loop, like ``dataDict = {}``. This way it will be in the correct scope when you print it after the loop.